# Python cgi.FieldStorage() always returns a blank form, and can't read params from http POST

Tags: python, http

I'm attempting to get a basic Python webserver example going that receives data from a http POST.  I'm currently using Postman to send the http POST as follows:

[image]

Here is my Python script:

```
# simple_web_server.py

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import cgi

###################################################################################################
def main():
    myRequestHandler = MyRequestHandler
    socketTCPServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), myRequestHandler)
    print 'starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    socketTCPServer.serve_forever()

###################################################################################################
class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print "in do_GET(self)"
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        print "in do_POST(self)"        # this shows successfully to the command line

        form = cgi.FieldStorage()

        print cgi.print_form(form)      # this always prints an empty form

        print str(form.getvalue('name'))        # this always prints an empty string

        if "name" not in form or "addr" not in form:        # the if never runs
            print "Please fill in the name and addr fields."
        else:
            print "<p>name:", form["name"].value
            print "<p>addr:", form["addr"].value

        self.wfile.write("test response 123 \n")    # this shows successfully in Postman
        self.send_response(200)                     # the 200 is successfully received by Postman

###################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are the command line results from Python when ran:

```
starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2016 20:02:33] "POST /?param1=value1&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
in do_POST(self)

<H3>Form Contents:</H3>
<P>No form fields.
<DL>
</DL>

None
None
Please fill in the name and addr fields.
```

As far as I can tell from the python.org docs and every example I could find I'm doing everything correctly but the form data is always blank.  Eventually I need to download a file sent by the POST but I'm going to hold off on that until I can read the form at all.  Has anybody else ran into this?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should mention that I just tried BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler in place of SimpleHTTPServer as above, did not make a difference.

Comment: I also tried CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler, still the same result

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think if you're running a base server like this, then you access the POST data via:

```
content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
```

If you wanted to access the POST data using

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

you would access that ***outside*** the base server class.  So in the main method or something like that.